# Android studio seems to be running a wrong fish after i changed to fish as main shell

Tags: flutter, android-studio, fish

Basically, if I open a Terminal it opens it with fish automatically, and if I enter 'flutter' it works. If, however, in Android studio in the fish terminal (which i set as defauly), the behaviour is rather strange. To show what happens i tried it in the terminal in AS:

```
⋊> ~/path ⨯ flutter                                            15:43:20
fish: Unknown command: flutter
⋊> ~/path ⨯ which fish                                         15:43:25
/usr/local/bin/fish
⋊> ~/path ⨯ fish                                               15:43:33
⋊> ~/path ⨯ which fish                                         15:43:53
/usr/local/bin/fish
⋊> ~/path ⨯ flutter                                            15:43:58
Manage your Flutter app development.
⋊> ~/path ⨯ exit
⋊> ~/path ⨯ flutter
fish: Unknown command: flutter
```

It's like i have an aquarium of two fish and AS uses the wrong, not configured one. HOWEVER i checked android studio, and the one set in preferences is `/usr/local/bin/fish`. Does anyone have an idea what the problem could be, or some troubleshooting I could try?

Things i did try so far are restarting my PC and AS multiple times.

Comment: `status fish-path` will show you which fish is running. But to me this looks like `flutter`'s directory is not being added to your $PATH. To know why we need to know how it normally gets added - what does `which flutter` and `echo $PATH` show when flutter is available?

Comment: I have the same problem, except that `flutter` is in my PATH and I can run it from terminal (iTerm2) with no problem, but not from Android Studio's terminal. Running `echo $PATH` from iTerm2 results in the expected PATH, while running it from Android Studio's terminal will print only a few paths.

Comment: Running `status fish-path` on both iTerm2 and Android Studio's terminal prints the same path. However, running `echo $PATH` in Android Studio's terminal shows a very different result, and indicates that it's terminal does not include the same paths that it does when running from iTerm2. I don't know why, tho.

Answer (score 0):

It turned out this was, as @ridiculous_fish pointed out in the comments, an issue of the wrong flutter path in the the path. Why opening a new fish worked i have no idea